# Javafx database PlatformFactory.getPlatform()

Tags: javafx, gluon

I have tried to use

```
PlatformFactory.getPlatform().getPrivateStorage()
```

but it states that cannot find symbol...

help please

Comment: Add more details about your IDE, Gluon's plugin version, post your build.gradle file or at least the part of it where you add Charm-Down dependencies...

Answer (score 2):

Just add this into you build.gradle:

```
ext.CHARM_DOWN_VERSION = '1.0.0'
dependencies {
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    desktopRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    androidRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
    iosRuntime "com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:$CHARM_DOWN_VERSION"
}
```

José Pereda helped me with this some days ago.

Comment: When this helped you can you maybe tell?